# Cannot find Symbol request.getServletContext() while Build

Tags: java, servlets, compiler-errors, ant, classpath

I've been writing a script to build a project, create War File and Deploy it on Tomcat. I'm getting the following error while executing the script, specifically during the javac command.
Please note that I'm trying to it without Eclipse, so I cannot integrate Tomcat 7 directly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:ant="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" name="Build Script For Deploy" default="NN-build" >
   
   <!-- This sript will read required proeprty values from below properties file -->
   <property file="upgrade.properties" />
   
   <target name="NN-build" depends="compile" description="NN VM build target with CDT update" /> 
   
   <!--Keeping all the required jar files to classpath. 
   All the ANT tasks used in the rest of the script will be executed from below jar files Hence they need to be on classpth. -->
   <path id="svnant.classpath">
       <fileset dir= "${lib.dir}" >
            <include name= "**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>   

    <path id = "catalina-ant-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name = "catalina-ant.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="install" classname = "org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
        <classpath refid = "catalina-ant-classpath" />
    </taskdef>  

   <!-- Defining all the required ANT tasks which will be used in the rest of the script -->
    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
   

  <property name="src.dir" location="${dest.home}/src" />
  <property name="classes.dir" location="${dest.home}/build/classes"/>
  <property name="dist.dir" location="${dest.home}/WebContent/WarFile" />
  <path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dest.home}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>

    <!-- Target for deleting the existing directories-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>
  
  <!-- Target for creating the new directories-->
  <echo>....Creating new directories.... </echo>
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

    <!-- Target for compiling the java code-->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" 
    deprecation="false" optimize = "false" failonerror = "true" >
    <src path="${src.dir}" />
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>
  </target>
  
</project>

java:43: error: cannot find symbol ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();    [javac]                                         ^
    
[javac]   symbol:   method getServletContext()
[javac]   location: variable request of type HttpServletRequest
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
C:\task\task-upgrade.xml:97: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for
 details.
```

I was receiving the same error when I imported the project in Eclipse, but adding the Server Runtime as Tomcat7 fixed it there.

Comment: You should add the same server runtime to property `compile.classpath`.

Answer (score 0):

When building a J2EE application, the classpath used to compile needs to be different from the one used at runtime. Because your web application is using a J2EE API, it needs to be compile against it. But once deployed, these API are provided by the container of your choice, here Tomcat, so they should not be part of your web application.

So in your concrete exemple, you need the javax servlet-api. Its jar needs to be added to your compile classpath, but not put into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Here is a list of jars which might fit your need:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:javax.servlet%20AND%20a:javax.servlet-api&core=gav

https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.tomcat%20AND%20a:tomcat-servlet-api&core=gav